# Not able to create graph with native projection

Tags: neo4j

> I downloaded community edition Neo4j 4.3.3 I installed gds library
> 1.6.4 which is compatible with Neo4j 4.3.3 edition.
>
> I am trying to run example to find shortest distance given in
> https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/dijkstra-source-target/
>
> > CREATE (a: Location {name: "A" }), (b: Location {name: "B" }), (c:
> > Location {name: "C" }), (d: Location {name: "D" }), (e: Location
> > {name: "E" }), (f:Location{name: "F" }), (a)-[:Road {cost:50}]->(b),
> > (a)-[:Road {cost:50}]->(c), (a)-[:Road {cost:100}]->(d), (b)-[:Road
> > {cost:40}]->(d), (c)-[:Road {cost:40}]->(d), (c)-[:Road
> > {cost:80}]->(e), (d)-[:Road {cost:30}]->(e), (d)-[:Road
> > {cost:80}]->(f), (e)-[:Road {cost:40}]->(f) WITH a, b,c,d,e,f
>
> CALL gds.graph.create( 'myGraph', 'Location', 'ROAD', {
> relationshipProperties: 'cost' } )
>
> MATCH (start:Location{name:"A"}), (end:Location{name:"F"})
>
> CALL gds.shortestPath.dijkstra.write.estimate('myGraph', { startNode:
> start, endNode: end, relationshipWeightProperty: 'cost',
> writeRelationshipType: 'PATH' }) YIELD nodeCount, relationshipCount,
> bytesMin, bytesMax, requiredMemory RETURN nodeCount,
> relationshipCount, bytesMin, bytesMax, requiredMemory
>
> But I am getting error
>
> *Procedure call inside a query does not support naming results implicitly (name explicitly using `YIELD` instead) (line 22, column 1
> (offset: 504)) "CALL gds.graph.create('myGraph','Location','ROAD',"*
>
> Please anyone explain how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you running each query separately?

Comment: No. I am running the whole query fully..

Comment: that is your problem,,, run each query separately and it will work

Comment: Thanks. I will try each query separately.

Comment: Thanks. I tried separately and now it is working.